# Enabling S3 bucket as website using cli

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I figured out how to create an S3 bucket using aws command line. Is it possible to enable the s3 bucket I created as website using aws cli? The reason I'm doing this is because we're automating everything.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+cli+s3+website --> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/website.html

Comment: I got it working!